# How do I echo submitted values from settings.php to mainpage.php?

Tags: php

I'm basically trying to get the values submitted from settings so that when the user submits it, it is displayed onto mainpage.php. Here's the code from what I have in settings.php...

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
<a href="mainpage.php">Main Page</a>

<form action="" method="get">
<b>Bio</b>
<br>
<textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="result" value="result"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="bio">
</form>

<form action="" method="get">
<b>Hobbies</b>
<br>
<textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="result" value="result"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="hobbies">
</form>

<form action="" method="get">
<b>Past School</b>
<br>
<textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="result" value="result"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="school">
</form>

<form action="" method="get">
<b>Work History</b>
<br>
<textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="result" value="result"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="work">
</form>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Choose Profile Picture:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"> 
<input type="submit" name="pic" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is what I have for mainpage.php

```
<?php

?>

<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
<a href="settings.php">Settings</a>



</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're trying to pass these settings to mainpage.php, why are you using "get" in the various forms? Is there a reason they're all separate forms? Normally someone would use one form with "post" and have "action=" set to the page to sent the data to. Such as `<form action="mainpage.php" method="post">...`

Answer (score 0):

As Jenna R said, it is better to use POST, not GET.

Then each variable is referenced with `$_POST["name"]`, so `$_POST["result"]` and so on.

I suggest you start reading up on PHP and submitting forms securely if you are doing this for anything other than learning.  This is pretty basic, so it looks like you haven't opened up the manual or a book just yet.